# How to apply multiple criteria condition using apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
    A         B
0   Morning  NaN
1   24       afternoon
2   34       23
3   23       16
4   NaN      13
5   NaN      NaN
6   15.5     1
```

I want to have a new column 'sumA' which will + 2 for these cells (except string and NAN) , so i wrote the code below:

```
df['sumA'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x + 2 if (df['A'].notnull) and (type(df['A'])== int) else x )
```

i got the result below , it doesn't + 2 to these cells which i expected.
Could you please help assist on this?

```
     A          B               sumA
0   Morning     NaN              Morning
1   24         afternoon         24
2   34          23               34
3   23          16               23
4   NaN         13               NaN
5   NaN         NaN              NaN
6   15.5        1                15.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert values to numeric with `errors='coerce'` for `NaN`s if not numbers and then add `2`, last if need non numeric values use `fillna`:

```
df['sumA'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').add(2).fillna(df['A'])
print (df)
         A          B     sumA
0  Morning        NaN  Morning
1       24  afternoon     26.0
2       34         23     36.0
3       23         16     25.0
4      NaN         13      NaN
5      NaN        NaN      NaN
6     15.5          1     17.5
```

Better if only numeric columns finally - numbers or missing values:

```
df['sumA'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').add(2)
print (df)
         A          B  sumA
0  Morning        NaN   NaN
1       24  afternoon  26.0
2       34         23  36.0
3       23         16  25.0
4      NaN         13   NaN
5      NaN        NaN   NaN
6     15.5          1  17.5
```

If need custom function:

```
#convert to numeric - if strings convert to NaNs
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')

#pass custom function
df['sumA'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x + 2 if pd.notna(x) else x )
print (df)
      A          B  sumA
0   NaN        NaN   NaN
1  24.0  afternoon  26.0
2  34.0         23  36.0
3  23.0         16  25.0
4   NaN         13   NaN
5   NaN        NaN   NaN
6  15.5          1  17.5
```

If really need mixing numeric and non numeric:

```
#convert strings numbers to numbers (float, int)
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['A'])

#apply function
df['sumA'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x + 2 if pd.notna(x) and not isinstance(x, str) else x)
print (df)
         A          B     sumA
0  Morning        NaN  Morning
1     24.0  afternoon     26.0
2     34.0         23     36.0
3     23.0         16     25.0
4      NaN         13      NaN
5      NaN        NaN      NaN
6     15.5          1     17.5
```

Comment: hi @jezrael, your suggestion is find for this question , but  in case i need to apply function for these cells which is numbers in column['A'], what should i do ? Appreciate for your assist.

Comment: @vanthang - answer was edited. Best is remove non numeric values - convert to NaNs

Comment: thank you so much Bro, your answer is very useful for me.